# Getting wrong file content when downloading file from server?

Tags: c#, php

I have a PHP script on our server that I use to download a file from `.NET/Unity3D`:

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$name_to_save = $_GET["name"];
$data_to_save = $_GET["data"];

$myFile = $name_to_save . ".txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $data_to_save);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

C# Upload code:

```
const string ServerSaveFile = "http://website.com/webserver/save-new.txt";
const string ServerPHPFile = "http://website.com/webserver/save-new.php";

IEnumerator AnotherUploadRoutine(string data)
{
    string url = ServerPHPFile + "?" + "name=" + "save-new" + "&data=" + data;

    WWW post = new WWW(url);
    yield return post;

    if (post.error != null)
        print("There was an error saving data: " + post.error);
}
```

Uploading works perfectly fine.

But when I try to download, I never get the downloaded values. I always get previous uploaded values.

C# Download code:

```
IEnumerator AnotherDownloadRoutine()
{
    var www = new WWW(ServerSaveFile);
    yield return www;

    print(www.text);
}
```

I access the server folder via WinSCP (ftp protocol, port 21). That's why I can see that it's doing the upload correctly: I can see the content of the file.

Any idea what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Yield return THEN print? Are you sure that's right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?